# Trazer apenas os valores das chaves em Python

Tags: python

Eu preciso trazer de um `dict` apenas os valores da `chave['nota']`, porém ele só traz uma vez.

Seguem o código:

```
def AlunoeNota(disciplinas, nome):
print('Aluno da FHO '+nome + '- SI' )
for nota in disciplinas.get('nota'):
    print(nota)

dicfinal = {}
disciplina1 = {'nome': 'Python', 'sigla': 'F0D4', 'periodo': 'Noturno', 'nota': '10'}
disciplina1.update({'nome2': 'Redes', 'sigla2': 'CH4T0', 'periodo2': 'Noturno', 'nota2': '8'})
dicfinal.update(disciplina1)

AlunoeNota(dicfinal,'Duener')
```

Como podem ver, eu tenho dois `dict` que fiz a junção, porém ele sempre traz o valor 10 sendo que eu preciso da nota 8 também, como faria nesse caso?

Comment: Tive que alterar as chaves pois se não, o update que é a junção não iria fazer ia substituir o atual. Existe alguma maneira diferente?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente isso:

```py
def AlunoeNota(lista, nome):
    print('Aluno da FHO ' + nome + '- SI' )
    for disciplina in lista:
        print(disciplina['nota'])

disciplina1 = {'nome': 'Python', 'sigla': 'F0D4', 'periodo': 'Noturno', 'nota': 10}
disciplina2 = {'nome': 'Redes', 'sigla': 'CH4T0', 'periodo': 'Noturno', 'nota': 8}
lista = [disciplina1, disciplina2]

AlunoeNota(lista, 'Duener')
```

Basicamente, cada dicionário deve ser 1 e apenas 1 registro de disciplina.

Tentar colocar dois registros no mesmo dicionário, vai criar uma gambiarra horrorosa e não é esse o caminho, ele deveria representar apenas uma coisa e não duas.

Para ter vários registros de disciplinas, você cria uma lista com dicionários.

E por fim, a nota é um número, e não uma string.

Comment: Cara muito obrigado, funcionou como eu queria.

Answer (score 2):

Como suas chaves no dicionário são diferentes, fazer o `get` colocando apenas um dos nomes, não vai funcionar.

Se você reparar bem, na verdade seu código está fazendo um loop no retorno da chave nota, imprimindo assim a string 10 em duas linhas:

```
for nota in disciplinas.get('nota'):
  print(nota)
```

Infelizmente está longe do que você deseja.

---

Existem inúmeras formas que você pode implementar isso, uma delas é imprimir todas as chaves que comecem com a palavra *nota*, para saber as chaves de um dicionário, você pode utilizar do método `keys`:

```
disciplinas.keys()
```

Tendo as chaves em mãos, você verificar se a chave começa com a palavra *nota*, para isso, utilize o método `startswith`:

```
chave.startswith("nota")
```

Agora juntando tudo, você teria o seguindo código dentro da função `AlunoeNota`:

```
  for key in disciplinas.keys():
    if key.startswith("nota"):
      print(disciplinas[key])
```

Essa instrução toda pode constar em apenas uma linha:

```
[print(disciplinas[key]) for key in disciplinas.keys() if key.startswith("nota")]
```

---

Outra forma, é alterar a função `AlunoeNota` para receber uma lista das chaves que serão impressas:

```
def AlunoeNota(disciplinas, nome, chaves):
  print('Aluno da FHO ' + nome + ' - SI' )

  for chave in chaves:
      print(disciplinas[chave])
```

Aí quando você chamar a função, você enviar o terceiro parâmetro falando quais chaves deseja imprimir:

```
AlunoeNota(dicfinal,'Duener', ["nota","nota2"])
```

---

Como ultima sugestão, você pode criar uma lista de dicionários, com isso, você terá apenas uma chave de nota, o que pessoalmente acho que fica muito melhor.

Eu teria os dois dicionários:

```
python = {'nome': 'Python', 'sigla': 'F0D4', 'periodo': 'Noturno', 'nota': '10'}
redes = {'nome': 'Redes', 'sigla': 'CH4T0', 'periodo': 'Noturno', 'nota': '8'}
```

Colocaria ambos em uma lista:

```
notasAluno = [python, redes]
```

Enviaria a lista para a função `AlunoeNota`:

```
AlunoeNota(notasAluno,'Duener')
```

E a função, faria um loop na lista, sempre imprimindo a chave nota:

```
def AlunoeNota(disciplinas, nome):
  print('Aluno da FHO ' + nome + ' - SI' )

  for dado in disciplinas:
      print(dado["nota"])
```

Com isso, você pode acessar os dados do dicionário de uma maneira muito melhor, podendo até formatar a saída, por exemplo:

```
print(f'A matéria {dado["nome"]} teve a nota {dado["nota"]}')
```

Comment: Incrível, você me deu varias maneiras de resolver meu problema, gostei muito da ultima por ser mais simples. Muito obrigado Daniel.

Answer (score 0):

De uma forma bem resumida,

seria isso:

```
dicfinal = {}
disciplina1 = {'Primeiro' : {'nome': 'Python', 'sigla': 'F0D4', 'periodo': 'Noturno', 'nota': '10'}}
disciplina1.update({'Segundo' : {'nome': 'Redes', 'sigla': 'CH4T0', 'periodo': 'Noturno', 'nota': '8'}})
dicfinal.update(disciplina1)



cont = 0
for item in (dicfinal):
    print(item)
    lista = list(dicfinal.values())
    print('Aluno da FHO '+lista[cont]['nome'] + '- SI' )
    print('Nota: '+lista[cont]['nota'])
    cont += 1
```

Acontece que só mudei um pouco a estrutura do dict, e vou pegando pelo índice.

**Resultado:**

Primeiro
Aluno da FHO Python- SI
Nota: 10

Segundo
Aluno da FHO Redes- SI
Nota: 8

Comment: Deu certo também, obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Baseado no [seu comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/438788/trazer-apenas-os-valores-das-chaves-em-python/438805#comment847533_438788):

> *Tive que alterar as chaves pois se não, o update que é a junção não iria fazer ia substituir o atual. Existe alguma maneira diferente?*

Sim, e as outras respostas indicaram um jeito, que é criar uma lista de dicionários. Mas ainda tem um porém: como você associa essas notas a um aluno? Pois o seu código permite que se faça isso:

```
AlunoeNota(lista, 'Duener')
AlunoeNota(lista, 'Fulano')
AlunoeNota(lista, 'Ciclano')
```

E as mesmas notas serão impressas como se fossem de 3 alunos diferentes. Não há qualquer relação entre as notas e o nome do aluno: a função `AlunoeNota` aceita qualquer lista de notas e qualquer nome, e assume que as notas são daquela pessoa.

---

Para relacionar a lista de notas com um determinado aluno, uma forma é criar um dicionário com a seguinte estrutura:

```
nome_aluno_1: [ lista de notas ],
nome_aluno_2: [ lista de notas ],
etc
```

Ou seja, a chave do dicionário é o nome do aluno, e seu valor é a respectiva lista de notas do mesmo (e essa lista contém vários outros dicionários, cada um representando uma disciplina). Então ficaria assim:

```
alunos_notas = {
    'Fulano': [ # notas do Fulano em cada disciplina
      { 'nome': 'Python', 'sigla': 'F0D4', 'periodo': 'Noturno', 'nota': 10 },
      { 'nome': 'Redes', 'sigla': 'CH4T0', 'periodo': 'Noturno', 'nota': 8 }
    ],
    'Ciclano': [ # notas do Ciclano em cada disciplina
      { 'nome': 'Python', 'sigla': 'F0D4', 'periodo': 'Noturno', 'nota': 5 },
      { 'nome': 'Redes', 'sigla': 'CH4T0', 'periodo': 'Noturno', 'nota': 2 }
    ]
}

def AlunoeNota(alunos_notas, aluno):
    if aluno in alunos_notas:
        print(f'Notas do {aluno}:')
        for disciplina in alunos_notas[aluno]:
            print(f'- {disciplina["nome"]}: {disciplina["nota"]}')
    else:
        print(f'Notas do aluno {aluno} não encontradas')

AlunoeNota(alunos_notas, 'Fulano')
AlunoeNota(alunos_notas, 'Beltrano')
```

Agora eu valido se as notas do aluno existem no dicionário, e só imprimo se existirem. A saída é:

```
Notas do Fulano:
- Python: 10
- Redes: 8
Notas do aluno Beltrano não encontradas
```

---

Você também pode, se quiser, criar uma função que imprime as notas de todos os alunos:

```
def mostrar_notas(alunos_notas):
    for aluno, disciplinas in alunos_notas.items():
        print(f'Notas do {aluno}:')
        for disciplina in disciplinas:
            print(f'- {disciplina["nome"]}: {disciplina["nota"]}')

mostrar_notas(alunos_notas)
```

Saída:

```
Notas do Fulano:
- Python: 10
- Redes: 8
Notas do Ciclano:
- Python: 5
- Redes: 2
```

Ou, para reaproveitar a primeira função já existente:

```
def mostrar_notas(alunos_notas):
    for aluno in alunos_notas.keys():
        AlunoeNota(alunos_notas, aluno)
```

---

Claro que a estrutura acima ainda é meio redundante, pois ela repete dados das disciplinas (em sistemas reais isso ficaria separado, mas aí já foge demais do escopo da pergunta).